# Connecting two dynamically created select elements

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, flask

I am somewhat stuck on this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

In my web app's(Flask) settings view i need to make a part where i must connect two select elements which can be dynamically added and removed.

[image]

What i need is basically to connect the select elements in each row, preferably as key:value (1st column, 2nd column).

Here is the jquery and html part where i create and fill selects:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mul_field_wraper').each(function() {
    var $wrapper = $('.mul_fields', this);
    $(".add_select", $(this)).click(function(e) {
      var obj = $('.mul_field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').end().find('option').focus();
    });

    $('.mul_field .remove_field', $wrapper).click(function() {
      if ($('.mul_field', $wrapper).length > 1)
        $(this).parent('.mul_field').remove();
    });
  });
});

function changeName(elem) {
  elem.setAttribute('name', elem.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="mul_field_wraper">
  <div class="mul_fields">
    <div class="mul_field">
      <select onchange="changeName(this);">{% for x in models %}
        <option value={{x[0]}}>{{x[0]}}</option>{% endfor %}</select>
      <select onchange="changeName(this);">{% for y in price %}
        <option value={{y[0]}}>{{y[1]}}</option>{% endfor %}</select>
      <button type="button" class="remove_field">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="add_select">Add field</button>
</div>
```

What i do right now is on change of the element, giving it name attribute same as value. But what i need to do is give it name to be same as value of adjacent select element.

Print of request.form when i POST my settings view gives me dict like this:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('model1', u'model1'),('model2', u'model2'),('price2', u'price2'),('price1', u'price1'),('price3', u'price3'),('model3', u'model3')])
```

And with dict like this i cant pair model1 with price1, model2 with price2 etc..

What i would need to achieve a dict simmilar to this:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('model1', u'price1'),('model2', u'price2'),('model3', u'price3'),('model1', u'price1'),('model2', u'price2'),('model3', u'price3')])
```

Where i would ignore the duplicate in python.

Again any help is appreciated, btw. is there a better way to handle this in general? How can i approach this better?

Answer (score 0):

I think that would be fairly easy thing to do.
When you create two select element in a row the row can be inside one div tag.

```
<div id='row'+fieldSet1>
    <coldiv>
        <select id='key'+fieldSet1>
        </select>
    </coldiv>
    <coldiv>
         <select id='value'+fieldSet1>
         </select>
    </coldiv>
</div>
```

Now using jQuery you can select the specific div row because you used dynamic ‘fieldSet#' for key as well as row and then get the values as key value pair and do whatever with it. I hope you get the idea.

Currently posting from phone so cannot test and post a full working code.

Comment: Could you elaborate more please?